# How many ways possible to (not properly) color a graph with k colors?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

#### Given any graph and k colors, how many ways can I make a defective coloring of the graph such that no 2 are isomorphic?

#### [example of all combinations for a C3 and 3 colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qiqr.png)

I don't really need to solve for every graph and every color, just for small numbers, at most 5 or 6 vertice graph (but it's already a lot of graphs) and 4 colors.

---

What I have tried so far:

I searched for defective graph coloring and graph labeling but haven't found anything. I'm currently trying to see if I can brute force all results using a program, but I realized it's going to take a very long time and wanted to know if this question could help me before.
I think there might be a logic using induced sub graphs, but I couldn't figure out yet.

Comment: This is a really nice question. I recommend looking at the two most extreme cases first. One is the case where the graph has no non-trivial automorphisms, that is every point can be uniquely identified from the graph structure. In that case the problem (for a six vertex graph) is equivalent to coloring the numbers 1 through 6 with $k$ colors and obviously the answer is $k^6$.

Comment: The other extreme is the one you drew, where the graph is a complete graph on $n$ vertices and every permutation of the vertices is a graph isomorphism. Here the coloring is determined by the number of red vertices, the number of blue vertices etc so you want to count the number of ways to write the number of vertices as a sum of $k$ smaller (possibly zero, but never negative) numbers where order matters (3 = 1 + 2, so 1 green, two blue, is different from 3 = 2 + 1, so two green one blue). There is a very neat trick for calculating this number, sometimes referred to as the 'stars and bars'

Comment: Of course the real magic happens when the graph is in between the two extremes, i.e. the graph has some symmetries but not so many as the complete graph. Perhaps we should brute force some small examples (e.g. the path graph on 3 vertices) to get some intuition for this case

Comment: Those are good starting points, I'll see what I can do. But I found a few codes online that check whether 2 graphs are isomorphic, I'll probably build on top of them and try to make the brute force test. If I don't give up on this problem, you may hear from me in a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a program to brute force examples. I forgot to mention that I only wanted connected graphs, and the results are only for connected ones.

Also, holy spaghetti, I think I reached exponential complexity. [The results are in this spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cUhUSJ3kFLhHx45FEBE3ebQ45pDDk11SKwh1NTFw_6I/edit#gid=0)

I checked small tests by hand (I drew all the graphs) to ensure the algorithm's correctness, but I couldn't do it for bigger tests. So you'll just have to believe it that it works. For 1 color it generated the correct number up to 7 vertices (I used [All Small Connected Graphs](http://www.cadaeic.net/graphpics.htm) as a reference), so it's probably correct.

For now this answer is what I needed, but if someone is into making a complete mathematical proof, feel free.